# Python match whole file name, not just extension

Tags: python, regex

**Objective:**
Use Python regex to return a list of filenames have certain file extensions.

**List of files:**

- X8SIA9.ROM
- X8SIA0.rom
- X8SIA0.928

**Regex to find files that end in *.ROM or 3x numbers:**

```
bios_file = re.findall(r'.*\.(rom|[0-9]{3})+', name, re.I)
```

**Issue:**
bios_file is returning `['ROM'], ['rom'], [928]`. bios_file should be returning the entire filename `['X8SIA9.ROM'],` etc. How can I have the full filename returned instead of just the file extension?

Comment: how are you getting the filenames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not capturing the whole filename in the group. You can also use noncapturing groups with `(?:...)`.

```
.*\.(rom|[0-9]{3})+ # from this
(.*\.(?:rom|[0-9]{3})) # to this
```

Comment: Using non-capturing groups is the right way to go.  There is, however, a relatively simple regex that uses no groups: `.*\.rom|.*\.[0-9]{3}`.  This trades off using groups with having to repeat `.*\.`.